# MY SonarQube C++ scan is successful but results only flag Duplications and none other where flagged

Tags: c++, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, sonarscanner

MY SonarQube C++ scan is successful but results only flag Duplications and none other where flagged, which seems their is some thing going wrong with the scan. I have looked at jenkins output and Background tasks none of them have any errors.

Have anyone faced this before? How can i overcome this issue?

Please give some suggestions.
Thanks in Advance.

```
**sonar-project.properties**
# Default SonarQube server
sonar.host.url=xxxxxxxx

# Root project information
sonar.projectKey=xxxxxx
sonar.projectName=xxxx
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Metadata
sonar.links.homepage=
sonar.links.ci=xxxx
sonar.links.scm=xxxx
sonar.links.issue=xxxx

# Sources to scan
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.projectBaseDir=system
sonar.sources=xxxx
sonar.exclusions=xxxx

# SonarCFamily configuration
sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output=build_output
sonar.cfamily.threads=1
sonar.language=cpp
sonar.log.level=TRACE|DEBUG
```

```
**Jenkins Output**
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /opt/sonar-scanner-3.3.0.1492-linux/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: /project-root/sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.3.0.1492
INFO: Java 1.8.0_212 IcedTea (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 3.10.0-1062.4.3.el7.x86_64 amd64
INFO: SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/bin/sq.keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
INFO: User cache: ?/.sonar/cache
INFO: SonarQube server 7.9.1
INFO: Default locale: “en_US”, source code encoding: “UTF-8”
WARN: SonarScanner will require Java 11+ to run starting in SonarQube 8.x
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=174ms
INFO: Server id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
INFO: User cache: /project-root/?/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load/download plugins
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=78ms
INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=6226ms
INFO: Loaded core extensions: developer-scanner
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Execute project builders
INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=7ms
INFO: Project key: org.wabtec.pdsserver
INFO: Base dir: /project-root/system
INFO: Working dir: /project-root/system/.scannerwork
INFO: Load project settings for component key: ‘XXXXXXXXXXX’
INFO: Load project settings for component key: ‘XXXXXXXXX’ (done) | time=23ms
INFO: Load project branches
INFO: Load project branches (done) | time=21ms
INFO: Load project pull requests
INFO: Load project pull requests (done) | time=15ms
INFO: Load branch configuration
INFO: Load branch configuration (done) | time=2ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=57ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=786ms
INFO: Indexing files…
INFO: Project configuration:
INFO: Excluded sources: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
INFO: 10342 files indexed
INFO: 0 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
INFO: 0 files ignored because of scm ignore settings
INFO: Quality profile for c: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for cpp: Sonar way
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on module PDS Server NS
INFO: Load metrics repository
INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=22ms
INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java]
INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java] (done) | time=23ms
INFO: Sensor HTML [web]
INFO: Sensor HTML [web] (done) | time=40ms
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=23ms
INFO: Sensor CFamily [cpp]
INFO: Using build-wrapper output: /project-root/build_output/build-wrapper-dump.json
INFO: Available processors: 8
INFO: Using 1 thread for analysis according to value of “sonar.cfamily.threads” property.
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=145ms
WARN: Metric ‘comment_lines_data’ is deprecated. Provided value is ignored.
INFO: 0 compilation units analyzed
INFO: Sensor CFamily [cpp] (done) | time=16616ms
INFO: Sensor JavaSecuritySensor [security]
INFO: Reading type hierarchy from: /project-root/system/.scannerwork/ucfg2/java
INFO: Read 0 type definitions
INFO: Reading UCFGs from: /project-root/system/.scannerwork/ucfg2/java
INFO: No UCFGs have been included for analysis.
INFO: Sensor JavaSecuritySensor [security] (done) | time=7ms
INFO: Sensor CSharpSecuritySensor [security]
INFO: Reading type hierarchy from: /project-root/system/ucfg_cs2
INFO: Read 0 type definitions
INFO: Reading UCFGs from: /project-root/system/ucfg_cs2
INFO: No UCFGs have been included for analysis.
INFO: Sensor CSharpSecuritySensor [security] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor PhpSecuritySensor [security]
INFO: Reading type hierarchy from: /project-root/system/.scannerwork/ucfg2/php
INFO: Read 0 type definitions
INFO: Reading UCFGs from: /project-root/system/.scannerwork/ucfg2/php
INFO: No UCFGs have been included for analysis.
INFO: Sensor PhpSecuritySensor [security] (done) | time=1ms
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on project
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=68ms
INFO: 548 files had no CPD blocks
INFO: Calculating CPD for 8453 files
INFO: CPD calculation finished
INFO: Analysis report generated in 2580ms, dir size=100 MB
INFO: Analysis report compressed in 14394ms, zip size=32 MB
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 2595ms
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
INFO: Analysis total time: 52.906 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 1:02.029s
INFO: Final Memory: 58M/1665M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Just can give you a direction what to search.
You need to install plugins from Sonar Marketplace on Sonar server (search in UI), cause by default you see only Zero Coverage Sensor.
Also you need to run unit tests (tests have to come with code) to send generated reports into Sonar and get also Coverage report

Comment: I have SonarCFamily plugin Installed and at this moment i am not looking for COverage.

Comment: Did you run scan on source code or on compiled? You need to scan source code and stop build if Quality Gate check failed. For now you analyzed only 6 files from all 548. I'm not big fan of Microsoft products so don't remember what I did on my old projects, but it still looks like your CFamily scanner is not activated for your code as well. Check again all options in Sonar GUI at marketplace for wright scanner, probably you need also get something from Nuget

Comment: I have attached the full output for more details, i have verified every thing even C++ plugin seems activated.